# Weird Chrome issues, code only works when refreshed

Tags: jquery, google-chrome

This code works perfectly in Firefox, in Chrome the 'read more' link I add if the car description is longer than 120 chars only works if you make a change to the code and then refresh. It's not the actual code change, it can just be adding or removing some spaces, but it seems to be some cache issue.....I think. Here's a code pen http://codepen.io/DuckofDeath/pen/Lzkvm. I didn't include the PHP code as that doesn't seem to be the issue.

```
<div id="partsDisplay">

</div>
```

Here's the page:http://www.modernmediaworld.com/diaboli/diaboliCars14.php

Also, when clicking on the '(More)" link instead of the panel opening it shows the panel # in the url.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem. Furthermore, there is not enough information to help you.

Comment: Ok....what topic would it be 'on topic' for?

Comment: it seems you have a problem with Google Chrome. Try checking with their support forums. https://support.google.com/chrome/?hl=en#topic=3227046

Comment: Why is this off topic if the topic is "google chrome"? especially when the link you sent me too had a link right back here it it seems to be the only place to address these issues. You are not helpful.

Comment: I don't make the rules. I only enforce them.

Comment: Turns out Chrome caches files forever, u have to turn on developer console, then right click reload and select ' clear cache and hard reload ' to get an up to date file and things work fine. Which BTW I found at the 'Gooogle Chrome at Stack OVerflow' link they had which would suggest you need to update the rules youre enforcing.

Answer (score 0):

To end this cleanly. If any new developer runs into this w/ Chrome simply download the "Cache Killer" add on for Chrome to force it to act like other browsers as far as refreshing changes in your code.